# Unable to refresh svg chart on Data Change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, svg

I have a heatmap designed on d3js. I have added two filters for sorting the data. When I'm changing the filters I see the updated data in the console and the chart refreshes. But after each refresh, the earlier visualized chart still remains.

I have tried `.remove()` and `.exit` from d3. These didn't seem to work.

Here's the link for my code in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/5x6qkjw6kp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Quick Answer

The way you have your code setup, you are calling the whole heatmap creation function every time a filter changes, so you're reading data, axes, everything again. Based on that, you could easily clear all elements on the chart and have them recreated from scratch, rather than using the true enter, exit, update pattern, by putting this line before you define your chart.

```
d3.select(".chart").selectAll("*").remove();
```

So your code will now look like

```
//Setting chart width and adjusting for margins
d3.select(".chart").selectAll("*").remove();
const chart = d3
    .select(".chart")
    .attr("width", width + margins.right + margins.left)
    .attr("height", height + margins.top + margins.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr(
      "transform",
      "translate(" + margins.left + "," + margins.top + ")"
    );
```

## Enter Exit Update

This section has been heavily edited, but looking through the code, quite a lot of changes would have to be made to adapt it to make it use Enter/Exit/Update type processes. Think about putting the main creation steps at the start of the chart creation outside of the function, as these only need to run once at load (titles, axes, things like that). Clicking new elements would then not recreate the whole chart, but just alter the dataset used to create the rect objects.

This works by removing all elements which are children of the main chart group before the chart is recreated.

Hope that makes sense, let me know if anything is unclear and I'll tidy it up!

Comment: Many thanks for the code. But even with the changes, you've suggested the chart is overlapping when being rendered.

Comment: Hi Rohit, I've altered the answer to give you a new one line quick fix, and explained a bit more why Enter/Exit/Update won't work easily on this existing code without a bit of rework.

Comment: This one now works perfectly fine. Many thanks for that. Also, do you have any idea how I can set a default background color for the chart? Now after plotting the data, there are white spaces between the blocks. I know I can achieve it by taking data from the matrix as input method. Is there any other alternative with which I can put a background color on the chart?

Comment: One easy way is to draw a Rect element inside the main "g" defined in the const chart section. Then you set that rect to the height and width of your chart, set the background colour, and you're done!

Comment: That worked for creating the `rect` but post this my main chart disappears.

Comment: You need to make sure that the rect is created before you create your first "g" element. So when defining the chart element, add the rect before the very first "g". This means all elements added later will go on top of the rect.

Comment: Tried that. But still the same error. Below is the snippet of my code. Can you suggest the changes I need to make?

`const chart = d3
          .select(".chart")
          .append("rect")
          .style("fill", "#FF00FF")
          .attr("width", width + margins.right + margins.left)
          .attr("height", height + margins.top + margins.bottom)
          .append("g")
          .attr(
            "transform",
            "translate(" + margins.left + "," + margins.top + ")");`

Comment: You need to move the rect to a separate line, you can't add a "g" as a child of a rect. Add the rect to the main chart, and add the g to the main chart afterwards. You will need 2 statements to do this, not 1 statement.

Alternatively, add the "g", then straight after add a rect as the first child of the chart object. Both will work.

Comment: That worked. You've been of great help for me. Thank you so much. :)